# Export Splunk result 15000 output mail in CSV

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

My Splunk result set is giving output of 15000 record (sometimes more then that) but when I set query as an alert to send the result set in CSV file the result is getting limit to 10001 records only.
Can anyone help that how can I get all 15000 record in CSV file in a mail via alert setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to edit and modify limits configuration :

edit  :  $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/system/local/limits.conf

```
[scheduler]
max_action_results = 20000
[searchresults]
maxresultrows = 20000</code>
```

edit  : $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/system/local/alert_actions.conf

```
[default]
maxresults = 20000</code>
```